# Meaning of "No man was less fitted by temperament for the necessary drudgery and worry"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I came across this sentence but can't understand the meaning. I understand the individual words though.

> No man was less fitted by temperament for the necessary drudgery and worry.

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

We seem to be talking about a job: one that requires drudgery and worry.

> He was the the most unsuitable man in the world for that job as it was not in his
> nature to worry or to do dull, menial work.

It is colourful writing and perhaps a little old-fashioned in its use of exaggeration. "No man" suggests "no man in the world". It's unusual to say any job *requires* or *demands* *worry*, but that is what "necessary" means here.

(colourful is 'colorful' in the US.)